# jQuery toggle activating on its own

Tags: jquery

Here's my code so far,

```
$("#mobile-menu").toggle(function(){
        $("#nav").animate({height:460},500);
      },function(){
        $("#nav").animate({height:65},500);
     });
```

I have a very similar set up on a different site and it works when clicking on `$("#mobile-menu")` to increase the height of the #nav tag, but in this case the code just starts up running when the page loads and causes the elements to animate away.

What am I missing here? Thank you

UPDATE

Here's my updated code, still not working as intend, the element just fades away. How is this done now with the new jQuery library?

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(function() {

        $("#nav").toggle(function(){
            $(this).animate({height:460},500);
          },function(){
            $(this).animate({height:65},500);
         });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said in the previous answer it is the result of the removal of support for [toggle(function(){}, function(){})](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

```
var $nav = $("#nav");
$('#mobile-menu').click(function() {
    var toggle = $nav.data('toggle-state');

    $nav.stop().animate({
        height: toggle ? 460 : 65
    }, 500);
    $nav.data('toggle-state', !toggle);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3tEc6/)

Comment: Well that sort of worked, but I'm having to click on it twice for it to fully open.

Comment: then switch the condition `toggle ? 460 : 65` to `toggle ? 65 : 460`

Answer (score 3):

Your other code is likely using an older version of jQuery.  This version of `toggle` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.  This is probably a result of the other `toggle` being called instead.

[Toggle Event (removed in 1.9)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

[Toggle Effect](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)